# Read, Modify the xml save it in a new xml using python

Tags: python, xml, xmltodict, dicttoxml

Below are the steps I am following:

1. Reading the xml file as dictionary

   ```
   import xmltodict

   with open("example.xml") as sxml:
       data = xmltodict.parse(sxml.read())
   ```
2. Changing the value

   ```
   data["key"]["key1"] = "some value"
   ```
3. I want to save the changes in **example.xml** file or I want to create a new file and save the changes.

How can I do it?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest you to be more specific in what you need, and also format your code so that it's easier to read for others. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

Following [README](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict#roundtripping) we can simply do

```
with open('example.xml', 'w') as result_file:
    result_file.write(xmltodict.unparse(data))
```

if you want to overwrite **example.xml** OR

```
with open('result.xml', 'w') as result_file:
    result_file.write(xmltodict.unparse(data))
```

if you want to create new file **result.xml**.

Comment: I am reading both options several times but can not find the difference. Can you give me an hint of difference between OR and NEW variant?

Comment: @TibSchott: the only difference is in names of files, OP asked about overwriting original file OR creating of a new file

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:

```
from lxml import etree

with open('yourxmlfile.xml', encoding='utf8') as inputfile:
    contents = inputfile.read()
parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
tree = etree.XML(contents, parser)
root = tree
#make some edits to root here
with open('yourxmloutput.xml', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    outfile.write(etree.tostring(root))
```

docs on the xml module can be found [here](https://lxml.de/)